# How could i convert with an extension of NumberFormatter a String to a Float

Tags: swift, string, integer, converters, separator

I have created an extension of NumberFormatter and binaryInteger, to convert Int to String with a space between thousands like thise: 11111 -> 11 111
Now, in another place, i need to reverse the convertion from a specific string to a Float , like this: 11 111 -> 11111.

Here is the first extensions of NumberFormatter and  BinaryInteger:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
        formatter.allowsFloats = true
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension BinaryInteger {
    var formattedWithSeparator: String {
        return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

So, how could i code an another extension, to make the reverse process?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
extension String {
    func backToFloat() -> Float {
      // Make a copy of original string
      var temp = self

      // Remove spaces
      temp.removeAll(where: { $0 == " " })

      return Float(temp) ?? 0.0
    }
}

print("1 234 567.2".backToFloat())
// log: 1234567.2
```

To enable `Float -> String` and `Double -> String`:

```swift
extension FloatingPoint {
    var formattedWithSeparator: String {
        return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

print(12345678.12.formattedWithSeparator)
// log: 12 345 678.12
```

Comment: thank you a lot. it works :)
please Eric, could you tell me if my initial code work with int to string, or float to string, or both?

Comment: The formatter works for both and it will also work for double to string. You simply need to implement `formattedWithSeparator` for `FloatingPoint` protocal. I edited my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same `withSeparator` formatter, and add another extension to `BinaryInteger`:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    init?(fromStringWithSeparator string: String) {
        if let num = NumberFormatter.withSeparator.number(from: string)
            .map({ Self.init(truncatingIfNeeded: $0.int64Value) }) {
            self = num
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I basically parsed the number into an `NSNumber`, and then converted that to an `Int64`, then converted that to whatever type of `BinaryInteger` is required. This won't work for the values of `UInt64` that are outside of the range of `Int64`, as the first conversion will convert them to a negative number. So if you want to handle those numbers as well, you should write another `UInt64` extension:

```
extension UInt64 {
    init?(fromStringWithSeparator string: String) {
        if let num = NumberFormatter.withSeparator.number(from: string)?.uint64Value {
            self = num
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```